# setd already serialized JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

On my server i have already serialized JSON to answer:

When I using Ok(string) it is serializing it again.

This is my function

```
public IHttpActionResult Logon([FromBody]Logon_Request model)
{
        string Answer= Get_Answer(model);

        return Ok(Answer); //not working
        return Ok(model);  //working fine
}
```

As the answer on the browser site instate of this

```
{
  "Token": "User token"
}
```

I have this

```
{\"Token\":\"User token\"}
```

Can you help me please:

-Can I prevent serialization?

-Do I need to use other types of return?

Comment: To return a string as-is, see duplicate [How to return raw string with ApiController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046417/how-to-return-raw-string-with-apicontroller). You shouldn't want to though, you generally want to let WebAPI handle the serialization: let the method `Get_Answer` return the answer _object_, not the serialized string. Then `return Ok(answer)` will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. Answer you point to is not ok: Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'. And return object is not a case for me.

Comment: Then change the return type of your API method to `HttpResponseMessage` or see [Why should I use IHttpActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. `public HttpResponseMessage Logon` will not show the compiler error you show if you use `return new HttpResponseMessage(...)`.

Comment: It is ok. Was my mistake. It is working. Thank you. Should I delete answer? It is really duplicate.

Comment: No, just leave it, it will help more people find that answer by the wording of your question. :) Happy to help.

Comment: One more question, please: if I want to use async version of Logon like this "public async Task<string> Logon()" instate of my Logon function it is possible?

Comment: See [async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get VS HttpResponseMessage Get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902275/async-taskhttpresponsemessage-get-vs-httpresponsemessage-get). If you use `Task<string>` you're back to the root of your question, as WebAPI will handle the serialization again.