# C# There Is No Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I read a stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902806/4573839), and in that answer it says `There is no Thread` in his [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), but the article is complicated that I can't easily understand the core idea, can anyone judge whether `There is no Thread` is true, if true can help to explain the core idea simpler and easier?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If async-await doesn't create any additional threads, then how does it make applications responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

Comment: I don't have time to write you a summary of the linked articles, but since you seem to lack an understanding of how `async` works, I would recommend you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) to get a better understanding of `async` as a concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's just saying that *while a task is being awaited* there is no thread actually waiting for it. That's all.

That's a good thing.